# c# creating a small program that will listen to directories and create files as a SERVICE

Tags: c#

process:

1. i need to make a program that will always be running in the background
2. it will look at 5 different directories
3. as soon as there are new files in those directories, it will create similar versions of those files in a new directory

questions:

1. when i go to new-->project. should i select SERVICE? ive never done this before
2. how do i ensure that this program is always running even if the operator restarted the computer? - maybe i should be running it from a server or something?

Comment: Whoa!  It's Jon's little brother!  You've got big shoes to fill.

Comment: i inherited the good looks and he got the brains

Answer (score 2):

- As for the Directory watching you can use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). read the documentation on MSDN.
- And Yes you should make it as a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6.aspx)
- For starting Set the [StartType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.starttype.aspx) Mode to [Automatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicestartmode.aspx) in Service installer

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you should create a windows
   service for this. A windows can be
   set to start automatically when the
   machine is restarted.
2. If you are looking for file changes look
   into the [FileSytemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You'll want to build this as a Windows Service.  This will cause it to (if you configure it this way) startup immediately on system startup, and always be running in the background.

Look at [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) for monitoring the directories.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a Windows Service (you don't need to run it on a server, it will work on any computer) and look for files using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

Yes use the windows service project, when you register it as a windows service you can set the startup type to auto, in this way it will run anytime the computer be restarted.

You will need to use the FileSystemWatcher class to what over those folders, I suppose you know the rest, let me know if you need further details.

Comment: i think i will probably set it to run off a server. how would i have it look at multiple directories?

Comment: You need an instance for each folder.